# How to align a Input area center of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to crate a div and a text area. Here I want the text area at the center of the div. exact center of the div like using **margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto**. These functions are not working. but I don't want to use **margin-left: 20px  or 30px** something like this. Please give some advise. Thank you.

```html
<div style="width: 240px; border: 1px solid; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <input type="text" name="" class = "textarea" style="width: 150px; min-height: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Hi, I am a member of Footdrive!"><br/>

  <input class = "save" type="button" name="Save" value="Save">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the parent div the `text-align:CENTER;` property to make the  button and text area in the center.

```html
<div style="width: 240px; border: 1px solid; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align:center;">
  <input type="text" name="" class = "textarea" style="width: 150px; min-height: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Hi, I am a member of Footdrive!">
  <br/>
  <input class = "save" type="button" name="Save" value="Save">
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Could you accept the answer please by clicking the green checkmark below the vote down button on this answer? Thanks!